# How can I find users location when app is in background or killed state?

Tags: swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

I want to get a new location when my app is in the background or killed state. I searched a lot and found out the method in the Apple doc. **startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()** for updating location when app is in background or killed state. But when I try this method didn't getting the location in the killed state.
Here is my code :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }

//MARK: LOCATION MANAGER:
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let long :CLLocationDegrees = manager.location?.coordinate.longitude ?? 00.00000
        let lat :CLLocationDegrees = manager.location?.coordinate.latitude ?? 00.00000
        print(lat)
        print(long)
        let location = LocationTracking()
        location.latitude = lat
        location.longitude = long

        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(location, update: false)
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Error",error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if (status == CLAuthorizationStatus.denied) {
            print("Location access denied")
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to have the background modes capability on.

Comment: @ElTomato I have done already.

Answer (score 0):

After setting Background Modes Capabiity on, you can use startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges() instead of startUpdatingLocations(). This method notifies you of changes in 500 meters.

And you can read this quote by public api.

> Apps can expect a notification as soon as the device moves 500 meters or more from its previous notification. It should not expect notifications more frequently than once every five minutes. If the device is able to retrieve data from the network, the location manager is much more likely to deliver notifications in a timely manner.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423531-startmonitoringsignificantlocati